# What is byte data type in java and Why it is used?

Tags: java, types

I am little bit confused in a data type of java named byte data type and why they are used?

I don't have any idea about byte data type. Can anybody help me in resolving my problem ?

Comment: a google search would've been faster.

Comment: A `byte` is a fundamental unit of memory, file storage and network data transfer. All the data types you use in Java use one or more bytes. Without knowing what you are confused about, it's hard to know what you suggest than do more research. It's a bit like trying to learn maths and saying you find digits confusing.

Answer (score 1):

> byte: The byte data type is an 8-bit signed two's complement integer. It has a minimum value of -128 and a maximum value of 127 (inclusive). The byte data type can be useful for saving memory in large arrays, where the memory savings actually matters. They can also be used in place of int where their limits help to clarify your code; the fact that a variable's range is limited can serve as a form of documentation.

via: [Java Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)